# Subquery in Select Projections.constructor

Tags: mysql, hibernate, subquery, querydsl

Tried to write subqueries in Select clause with Projections like so

```
queryFactory.query()
            .select(
                    Projections.constructor(
                            MemberPaymentDTO.class,
                            JPAExpressions
                                    .select(coopMember)
                                    .from(coopMember)
                                    .where(memberPayment.memberId.eq(coopMember))
                                    .fetchOne(),
                            JPAExpressions
                                    .select(paymentTransaction.amount)
                                    .from(paymentTransaction)
                                    .where(paymentTransaction.transactionId.eq(memberPayment.paymentTransaction.transactionId))
                                    .fetchOne().floatValue(),
                            JPAExpressions
                                    .select(collectionTransaction.price.multiply(collectionTransaction.quantity).sum())
                                    .from(collectionTransaction)
                                    .where(collectionTransaction.member.memberId.eq(memberPayment.memberId.memberId))
                                    .where(collectionTransaction.paymentPeriod.paymentPeriodId.eq(paymentPeriodId))
                                    .fetchOne().floatValue()

            )
            .from(memberPayment);
```

The DTO is as follows

```
public class MemberPaymentDTO {
    private CoopMember coopMember;
    private float payableAmount;
    private float collectionsAmount;


    public MemberPaymentDTO(CoopMember coopMember, float payableAmount, float collectionsAmount) {
        this.coopMember = coopMember;
        this.payableAmount = payableAmount;
        this.collectionsAmount = collectionsAmount;
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is Intellij Compiler complains `Cannot resolve method 'constructor(java.lang.Class<re.iprocu.model.MemberPaymentDTO>, re.iprocu.model.CoopMember, float, float)`

Is it possible for one to add a subquery to select clause and set in a DTO? How?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with QueryDSL but the error is quite specific.

There is no constructor for that takes two float values which, in your case come from:

```
JPAExpressions
                                    .select(paymentTransaction.amount)
                                    .from(paymentTransaction)
                                    .where(paymentTransaction.transactionId.eq(memberPayment.paymentTransaction.transactionId))
                                    .fetchOne().floatValue()
```

and:

```
JPAExpressions
                                    .select(paymentTransaction.amount)
                                    .from(paymentTransaction)
                                    .where(paymentTransaction.transactionId.eq(memberPayment.paymentTransaction.transactionId))
                                    .fetchOne().floatValue()
```

The API http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.5/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/Projections.html states that the possible uses of Projections.constructor are:

```
constructor(Class<? extends T> type, Expression<?>... exprs)
Create a constructor invocation projection for the given type and expressions

constructor(Class<? extends T> type, Class<?>[] paramTypes, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList<Expression<?>> exprs)
Create a constructor invocation projection for given type, parameter types and expressions

constructor(Class<? extends T> type, Class<?>[] paramTypes, Expression<?>... exprs)
Create a constructor invocation projection for given type, parameter types and expressions
```

which means that you are not making the call correctly. Read the documentation more carefully and search for examples, basically you're misusing the API.

Comment: That's not really what this site is for, you can find tons of examples with a simple google, using the API the correct way is calling the API with the correct parameters at least (see link in the answer), what you're doing is impossible in java (passing wrong parameters into a method), doesn't even have anything to do with QueryDSL

Comment: I don't know how to do it the write way and as a stackoverflow rule, i need to show an attempt, trial...That code is my attempt